# How do I communicate between two different laravel projects on the same domain?

Tags: php, laravel

I have two different laravel projects on the localhost and I need to make a communication between them. When I do that, surprisingly I'll be kicked out of the current project I'm in. In other word, the session of the current project will be replaced *(I think)* with the second one *(when I make a connection to the second project)*.

I've tried to define two different domains for them to keep both session alive. By setting `SESSION_DOMAIN = my_first_prject`and `SESSION_DOMAIN = my_second_prject` into their `.env` files. But laravel doesn't accept this. It just accepts `SESSION_DOMAIN = localhost` which as I said causes *log out* when I switch from a project to other one.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Run them on 2 different domains.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use virtual host, if u use apache2 to serve laravel,
this is really easy to do that.

You can use same domain but maybe with virtual host you can use different port